# Add all-time column to meta user card drop down

Tags: feature-request, user-profiles, meta

By "user card drop down", I mean this:

> [image]

It'd be interesting to see the all-time +/– votes score in an additional column. It's not something that can be easily determined otherwise, since there's no `/reputation` for non-MSO Meta sites.

Comment: But there's no score for meta's except [metase] right? So why would you worry about that?

Comment: @jcolebrand There is *score* (which is what is displayed on the user card, and a user's profile, both in the tag list and the questions/answers list), but no *reputation*. I don't get reputation for the votes, but it's still interesting to see how controversial, popular, or unpopular my Meta contributions are. AFAIK, there is no way to determine it other than viewing the individual posts and clicking the total score.

Comment: Sorry, gamification leads me to always call reputation a "score" in times like this. If you don't care about the gamification, you don't care about rep. If you care about the gamification (which you're asking for features to help show the overall gamification) then you care about rep as score. Sorry that you don't see the conflation of the two, but it exists.

Comment: @jcolebrand What's your point? I said I wasn't interested in the rep that doesn't exist on Meta (you're right about that), but *am* interested in the number of up votes and down votes, which does exist and is shown in the screenshot for today/this week/this month. I don't care what the underlying concepts are in this context. I'd also be interested in the vote count if there *was* reputation (like the main site), because it's a surjective function of the votes and therefore loses information. I can get the missing data from `/reputation` though on the main site.